# iOS 9 selected tabor item background colour change

Tags: ios, swift3, tabbar

I wanna ask some question for Swift 3 (i mean iOS app development)

What I want to know is how to set a specific color to selected tabBar. Like in the picture the tabBar which is selected is having dark green color.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf5Wb.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set tabbar's tint color something like,

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

You can set tint color for selected tab like,

```
UITabBar.appearance().selectedImageTintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

You should write this code in appdelegate's didfinishlaunching or in first tab's viewdidload!

Comment: Hımm. yeah nice solution but i do not want this. I what that "selected background color"